# How do I fix this problem with While and For loop?

Tags: qbasic

I'm writing a program in QBasic that ask for peoples *names* and *ages* infinite times until I press **xxx** and the program then prints all those entered names and ages:

I keep getting **Zeros** instead of the *names* and *ages*, no matter how hard I try, I am totally stuck, below is my code:

```
DIM i AS INTEGER
CLS
i = 1
WHILE nam$ <> "xxx"
   Input "Enter name: ", nam$
   Input "Enter age: ", age$
   Sum$ = nam$ + age$ (i)
   i = i + 1
WEND
FOR x = 1 to i
    PRINT Sum(i)
NEXT x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same code only using while:

```
REM how to enter data and add to array using only while
DIM i AS INTEGER
CLS
DIM Sum(16384) AS STRING
PRINT "enter xxx to quit."
WHILE z = 0
    INPUT "Enter name: ", nam$
    INPUT "Enter age: ", age$
    IF nam$ = "xxx" THEN
        z = -1
    ELSE
        i = i + 1
        Sum(i) = nam$ + " " + age$
    END IF
WEND
FOR x = 1 TO i
    PRINT Sum(x)
NEXT x
```

Comment: It works, Can you please explain the Sum(16384)?
I don't understand it and I saw that without it there will be
**Illegal Sring-Number Conversion on line 13**

Comment: It is a large enough number to declare the array with that you will probably not get to.

Comment: If you don't dimension the array it defaults to 10 items only.

Comment: Well understood.

Answer (score 0):

The code is quite simple:

```
REM how to enter data and add to array
DIM i AS INTEGER
CLS
DIM Sum(16384) AS STRING
PRINT "enter xxx to quit."
DO
    INPUT "Enter name: ", nam$
    INPUT "Enter age: ", age$
    IF nam$ = "xxx" THEN EXIT DO
    i = i + 1
    Sum(i) = nam$ + " " + age$
LOOP
FOR x = 1 TO i
    PRINT Sum(x)
NEXT x
```

Comment: Okay this is the results I wanted but how do I accomplish same task with WHILE and FOR LOOP only

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for two arrays:

```
REM how to enter data and add to two arrays using only while
DIM Sum1(8192) AS STRING, Sum2(8192) AS INTEGER ' adjusted for qb45
CLS
PRINT "Press Enter to quit."
WHILE z = 0
    INPUT "Enter name?", nam$
    IF nam$ = "" THEN
        z = -1
    ELSE
        INPUT "Enter age?", age%
        i = i + 1
        Sum1(i) = nam$
        Sum2(i) = age%
    END IF
WEND
FOR x = 1 TO i
    PRINT "Name: "; Sum1(x); " Age:"; Sum2(x)
NEXT x
```